# Stripe Checkout not working in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, firefox, iframe, stripe-payments

I've integrated [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) on my Wordpress website via PHP Library.

Everything works great, but in Firefox the Stripe iFrame throws up the error:

"Security Policy: Directive 'frame-src' has been deprecated."

That's what the outer iFrame looks like

```
<iframe
   allowtransparency="true"
   style="
      z-index: 2147483647;
      display: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
      border: 0px none transparent;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      visibility: visible;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   "
   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/m/v3/index-af884f1198ee56a57968.html?distinct_id=3cc4aac1-0c17-892b-6ce9-340ee07ea9b2"
   name="stripe_checkout_app"
   class="stripe_checkout_app"
   frameborder="0"
>
...
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it. It will go away in future versions as `frame-src` is undeprecated in CSP Level 3: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#changes-from-level-2.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!

But how come that it interrupts my JS?

Comment: I'm fairly sure your error is unrelated to this warning. Do you have any browser extensions that could interfere with Checkout? Can you try in an incognito window to see if you observe the same error?

Comment: yes you're right, firefox just din't recognise a click event on a span element

Comment: Btw I've contacted Stripe and that's their answer:

"As you can read in https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#changes-from-level-1, the `child-src` CSP directive has deprecated and replaced the `frame-src` CSP directive. Our documentation has clearly not been updated to reflect this update.

So, what I would suggest is that you use the `child-src` directive instead of the `frame-src` directive."

Comment: I think whoever replied to you may have been confused and thought you were talking about your own CSP, not Checkout's. In any case, glad you got it sorted out! :)